# Como pesquisar uma string dentro de um objeto em um array?

Tags: javascript, array

Eu gostaria de procurar a palavra "roteiro" dentro de um objeto, que seria a variável `Roteiro`.

Comecei a tentar bolar alguma coisa depois de pesquisar na internet, mas já me perdi, e não deu certo, então preciso de ajuda com o raciocínio... 
como segue:

```
var Roteiro = {};
var roteiro = [{ descricaoRoteiro: "Descrição roteiro", idRoteiro: 1 }];
var perguntas = [{ tituloPergunta: "Titulo pergunta", idPergunta: 2 }];
var opcoes = [{ tituloOpcao: "Titulo opcao roteiro", idOpcao: 3 }];
Roteiro = { roteiro: roteiro, perguntas: perguntas, opcoes: opcoes};

for (var key in Roteiro) { 
    debugger;
    if(typeof(Roteiro[key]) == "object"){
        for (var key2 in Roteiro[key]){
            for (var key3 in Roteiro[key][key2]){
                for (var name in Roteiro[key][key2][key3].keys){
                    alert(Roteiro[key][key2][key3]
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depois de achar algum registo eu gostaria de pegar o "local" onde foi encontrada a palavra, é possivel?

Comment: Não sou muito bom em javascript, mas não teria um caminho mais fácil usando recursão ? algo do tipo...
[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/isvaldo/7f97b3c47f4fb5ac83c1)

Comment: As duas respostas retornam a primeira ocorrência encontrada. É disso que você precisa, ou precisaria retornar todas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não sabes a profundidade esse objeto o melhor é usar uma função recorrente do tipo:

```
function procurar(obj, agulha) {
    var chaves = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++) {
        var chave = chaves[i];
        if (!obj[chave]) continue;
        else if (typeof obj[chave] == 'object') return procurar(obj[chave], agulha);
        else if (obj[chave].indexOf(agulha) != -1) return [obj, chave];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Esta função "varre" cada propriedade do objeto, iterando sub-objetos/sub-arrays chamando-se novamente a sí própria, e retorna uma array com o sub-objeto e a chave que contém a string (agulha) procurada.

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/se93yyj7/**
que dá uma array com o objeto e a chave: `[Object, "descricaoRoteiro"]`

Answer (score 2):

Veja se essa solução te atende:

```
var resultSearch = [];

    for (var key in Roteiro) {

        Roteiro[key].forEach(function(value, key){

            for (k in value) {
                if (/roteiro/g.test(value[k])) {
                    resultSearch.push(value);
                }

            }
        });

    }

console.log(resultSearch);
```

Veja nesse [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vq8zz9Lk/)

A verificação é feita através de uma expressão regular, onde `/roteiro/g.test`  avalia se o valor atual do loop contém a palavra "roteiro". Assim, caso seja verdadeiro, o método `push` adiciona o valor em um novo `Array`, que é a nossa variável `resultSearch`.

Comment: Opção alternativa: `indexOf` em vez da expressão regular.

Comment: Melhorias são sempre bem-vindas, amigo @bfavaretto